# Função em Shell script sem retorno

Tags: linux, shell

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function ping {
nome=$(dialog --title "inform o endereço que deseja PINGAR" --inputbox "IP ou URL - \
Lembrando que será disparado 10 pings para o endereço informado." 10 45 --stdout)
status=$?
if [[ $status -eq 0 ]]; then
ping -c 10 $nome
rc=$?
if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "#####################################"
    echo "## Endereço: $nome | Status: UP"  
    echo "#####################################"
else
    echo "#####################################"
    echo "## Endereço: $nome | Status: DOWN"
    echo "#####################################"
fi; else; echo "Você optou por cancelar a operação."; fi; } valor=`ping`; echo "RESULTADO FOI: "$valor
```

Porem quando eu executo o script (`./meuscript.sh`), não tenho nenhum retorno, somente se eu seleciono cancelar no dialog.

Se executo o script sem a função, o comando é executado corretamente, me exibindo os 'echos' corretos.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Coloque o código em vez de colocar uma imagem do código. Torna mais simples responder a sua pergunta.

Comment: seguindo sua sugestão, feito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz a mesma pergunta em na versão em inglês e obtive a seguinte resposta!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31979174/function-shell-script-no-return-data/31979644#31979644

Deixo aqui registrado, caso alguém no futuro tenha a mesma dificuldade que tive!

Answer (score 2):

A função está muito confusa: tens simultaneamente o comando `ping` do sistema e a função `ping`.

Para experimentares devidamente o funcionamento da script muda o 
nome da função só então verás os resultados começar a aparecer:

```
function pingggg {
nome=$(dialog --title "inform o endereço que deseja PINGAR" --inputbox "IP ou URL - \
Lembrando que será disparado 10 pings para o endereço informado." 10 45 --stdout)
status=$?
if [[ $status -eq 0 ]]; then
  ping -c 10 $nome
  rc=$?
  if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "#####################################"
    echo "## Endereço: $nome | Status: UP"  
    echo "#####################################"
  else
    echo "#####################################"
    echo "## Endereço: $nome | Status: DOWN"
    echo "#####################################"
  fi
else
   echo "Você optou por cancelar a operação." 
fi; } 

valor=`pingggg`; echo "RESULTADO FOI: "$valor
```